# Teen fiction/sci-fi novel: main male character at a party on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification

I know that the opening scene of the book the main male character is at some sort of party on a space ship. The cover has a girl with red hair reaching for a boy- can't remember what he looks like -across, what I think is, the galaxy. Really liked the first few pages I read of this book, please help me find it! Just throw some random ideas out there if you have them, its also a fairly new book.

Comment: Additional detail would help.  Can you remember any character names, strange creatures, any plot elements, strange encounters, specific technologies used, etc?